# Enumerable or Linq Foreach loop for Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

this code print a dictionary key and value with separator .

```
public static void DictionaryPrint<T ,U >(IDictionary<T,U> dictionary,string separator = " ")
        {

            foreach (KeyValuePair<T, U> pair in dictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + separator + pair.Value);
            }
        }
```

Question : Can i write something like

```
 public static void DictionaryPrint<T, U>(IDictionary<T, U> dictionary, string separator = " ")
       {
            // this is for example , i now that dictionary doesn't have built-in ForEach mathod 
        
            dictionary.ForEach(KeyValuePair<T,U> kvp => Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + separator + kvp.Value)); 
       }
```

I need something like Java Stream Api . I tried Linq and Enumerable .

Comment: Why? The first snippet looks totally fine?

Comment: @Fildor Yes , i know but i need something like Java Stream API

Comment: In that case the dupe should be good. Mind that it basically just abstracts your first snippet to an extension method. So it will be not built-in but custom.